# How to pass parameters in jdbcTemplate for multiple parameter markers with same value?

Tags: java, sql, db2, jdbctemplate

I am having 4 same parameter markers in my query where I am passing "?" to fetch the data returned by
getMyDateField() function, Do I need to pass same parameter 4 times as below ? What is the correct way. Please suggest

```
  final String[] args = new Date[]{
        getMyDateField(),
        getMyDateField(),
        getMyDateField(),
        getMyDateField()
};
int[] types = new int[]{Types.CHAR, Types.CHAR, Types.CHAR, Types.CHAR};
result = jdbcTemplate.query(query, args, types, new Mapper());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need all 4 parameters to have the same date value and `getMyDateField()` is doing some processing, you can always store the result of getMyDateField() in a variable and pass it 4 times to the date array, making your code a bit more efficient.

If the sql query can be modified, i.e. you don't need 4 constraints on 4 parameters as they all share the same date value, then you could change the query to a `where date1 = date2 and date2 = date3 and date3 = date4 and date4 = ?dateparam` and pass that parameter only once.